# Summing rows based on matching column value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, subset

```
        c1       c2       count 
 1        1        1          20
 2        2        3          50 
 3        1        4          30
```

So I essentially have data like the table above but what I want to do is add a new column that has each row's count divided by the sum of counts of all rows with the same c1 value, ending up with something like:

```
        c1       c2       count    new_col
 1        1        1          20     20/50
 2        2        3          40     40/40
 3        1        4          30     30/50
```

As you can see, the new column has the row's count divided by the sum of all counts with matching c1 value.
So what I've been trying is something like this:

```
df$new_col <- df$count/sum(df[SUBSET OF ROWS THAT HAVE SAME c1 VALUE]$count)
```

I've seen something like df[df$c1 == some value,] but this would only work for like a hard coded value. I could also try using a for loop, but it takes way too long to iterate through every single row in my data and never finishes running, I also don't know all of the values that c1 takes. I'm pretty new to R and there may be a very simple solution to this but I haven't been able to come up with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- structure(list(c1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L), c2 = c(1L, 3L, 4L), count = c(20, 
40, 30)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
df %>% group_by(c1) %>% mutate(Sum=sum(count),NewVar=count/Sum)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   c1 [2]
     c1    c2 count   Sum NewVar
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     1    20    50    0.4
2     2     3    40    40    1  
3     1     4    30    50    0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option via `ave`

```
> within(df,new_col <- count/ave(count,c1,FUN = sum))
  c1 c2 count new_col
1  1  1    20     0.4
2  2  3    40     1.0
3  1  4    30     0.6
```

or via `rowsum` (by @akrun from comment)

```
> within(df,new_col <- count/rowsum(count,c1)[c1])
  c1 c2 count new_col
1  1  1    20     0.4
2  2  3    40     1.0
3  1  4    30     0.6
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(c1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L), c2 = c(1L, 3L, 4L), count = c(20, 
40, 30)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Another `base R` option is `with(df, count/rowsum(count, c1)[c1])`

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. I have added your approach to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.